# iOS - Trying to push a Storyboard from a RootViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, ios6

I'm trying to integrate Apple's simple Collection View sample into an project.

I have this code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    ImageViewController *ivc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"images"];

    NSLog(@"1");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"2");

}
```

I see the log statements but no view is pushed. I have set "images" as the Storyboard ID. This is my first work with Storyboard, so I'd appreciate any advice what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Replace `NSLog(@"1");` with `NSLog(@"DEBUG:  ivc = %@", ivc);` and `NSLog(@"DEBUG:  Nav Controller = %@", self.navigationController);`.  This will tell you which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, with that info, I came up with this: -(IBAction)photoButtonTapped:(id)sender {UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ImageStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 ImageViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImageView"];
 [self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];  
}

Comment: So your identifiers were wrong?  That fixed it?

Comment: Yes, they were not in sync and the navController was empty. That'll teach me to simply copy code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the diagnostic help of lnafziger, I resolved this with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)photoButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ImageStoryboard" bundle:nil];

ImageViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImageView"]; 

[self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```